Several file descriptors vs seeking all the time
I'm pondering a design for a parser library that needs to maintain several (on the order of 10) read streams to the same file with independent positions. I could do it by opening the file several times, or opening once and seeking whenever needed. On general grounds, which will provide better performance? The resource footprint will probably be worse under the multiple handles approach, but would that translate into a performance gain?
The answer will probably be rather platform dependent. Assume desktop Linux, with Windows being considered too. The project is in Python, but the underlying difference would be, I suspect, Python agnostic.

I can't imagine any significant performance difference.

Measure performance if it matters.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

I only embarked on this because of a performance bottleneck :)

What if you mmap the file (e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) ?
